# FFmpeg- waveform from audio with transparent background

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

If I use this command

```
ffmpeg -y -i <mp3> -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=375x244:colors=#ffffff" -vframes 1 test.png 2>&1
```

I get the output that I wanted. My only problem is that I do not want to store to disk and want to get a buffer to store as an image in S3.

To do that I use this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i <mp3> -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=375x244:colors=#ffffff" -vframes 1 -f mjpeg -
```

In which a get a buffer of the waveform on

```
runner.stdout.on("data", (data) => console.log(data));
```

The only problem is that from that image the Background is black.

My question is, how can achieve a transparent waveform without saving it to disk?

I do not want to use any library.

Comment: JPEGs don't store alpha. Save as PNG.

Comment: The problem of trying to store it as PNG is that it is expecting an output of video and then it complains about wrong format. `ffmpeg -y -i <mp3> -filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=375x244:colors=#ffffff" -vframes 1 -f png -, wont work. How can I change it?
`

Comment: Output options after the filter should be `-vframes 1 -c:v png -f image2pipe -`

Comment: Thanks!! It sorted that out, much appreaccited your help :)